# can an OAuth consumer app expose an API to an iOS app?

Tags: ios, oauth

I'm creating an app for iOS that consumes an API I've created, which requires authentication and authorization of users. I'm thinking of using OAuth to let the mobile users do this with Facebook. This is an internal API that isn't meant to be exposed to third parties.

Anyway, I'm a little confused about the abilities and limitations of OAuth consumers versus OAuth providers. Basically, I want to implement "Login with Facebook" functionality from the iOS app. It seems to me that this implies that my API should be an OAuth consumer, but the problem with this is that the login flow for a web app assumes a browser -- an `NSURLConnection` instance isn't going to know what to do with an HTML login page, and even if the redirect to the login page was made to work by prefixing the redirect URI with the `fb://` schema, surely the login form is going to pass the authorization token back to the iOS app and not my API?

So my question is: is there a way to implement my API as an OAuth consumer? If not, and I should implement it as an OAuth provider, what does logging in with credentials from another provider like Facebook even mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think things are a bit mixed up:

1. OAuth is to Authenticate your app against facebook. A user grants
   access to his FB account to your app on behalf of him
2. "Login with FB" is the other way round and is *not OAuth*: A User
   with an FB account is using this data to register AND login to your
   app.

The entire flow of the # 2 can be read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After reading this and some more googling I realized I was stupidly saying "login" when I meant "registration," which explains a lot of my trouble. One issue remains, though: the Facebook registration plugin is implemented as an iframe that you drop into your site. Is there any registration flow with Facebook that allows you to register for a website using plain HTTP requests? For some reason, it's really hard to find definitive information on this.